# An updated alternative to "A Panorama of Pure Mathematics"

Tags: math-history

Dieudonne's [A Panorama of Pure Mathematics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0122155602) serves as a nice, brisk overview of the state of pure mathematics at its time, but it would be nice if there were an updated version of this book.

Is there a more recent book with a similar style and scope to Dieudonne's book?

Thanks, in advance.

BTW: I tagged this as "math history", but would prefer it to be tagged as "math overview"...

Comment: 'Modern Mathematics in the Light of the Fields Medals'?

Answer (score 6):

Try *[The Princeton Companion to Mathematics](http://books.google.com/books/about/The_Princeton_Companion_to_Mathematics.html?id=ZOfUsvemJDMC)*.

Comment: I thought someone might volunteer this one. Is this significantly more lengthy...with an "encyclopedia" feel? Would this be readable as a whole? (Of course, I'll have another look!)

Comment: @Jon: I've read the whole thing, but I'm the only person I know who has (besides Gowers, I suppose). It is indeed structured like an encyclopedia, but since the entries are written by different authors I think you get the benefit of a wide variety of perspectives.

Comment: I thought so. Something I left hidden in my question is that I want the book to serve as a text for a course designed to "round out" a student's global perspective of mathematics. I'd therefore like it to be readable in its entirety...by an undergraduate of reasonable caliber.

Comment: @Jon: caliber has very little to do with it. I wasn't taking classes last semester, so I had a lot of time on my hands...

Comment: What's the intended audience?  Does a typical reader need a bit of a feel for most of the content before taking on the expositions in here?

Comment: @AsinglePANCAKE: I think it is a worthwhile investment as long as you plan on _eventually_ getting a feel for most of the content. As you progress mathematically you'll keep getting more out of it.

Comment: In some sense "A Panorama..." surveys more advanced math than the Companion even if outdated. Is a common myth that Hilbert was the last universalist but Dieudonné comes as an encyclopedist of mathematics as there was ever one so it is unrealistic to think someone can pull off a similar book, maybe Manin or Kazhdan would have made an attempt to it